# I couldnt insert data to PostgreSql table via c#,using function

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

My function(postgresql):

```
CREATE FUNCTION connec2(_X integer,_Y integer,_Z integer)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.polepoints (X,Y,X)
    VALUES(_X  , _Y  , _Z);
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

My C# code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int X = 500;
        int Y = 600;
        int Z = 700;
        string strReturn = "";
        string ConStr = "";
        string Code = "";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        NpgsqlParameter[] parameters =
                 {

                 new NpgsqlParameter( "_X", NpgsqlDbType.Integer) { Value = X } ,
                new NpgsqlParameter( "_Y", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 20) { Value = Y } ,
                new NpgsqlParameter( "_Z", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 20) { Value = Z } ,



                };
        ConStr = "Server = localhost; Port = 5433; User Id = postgres; Password = DoNotShareYourPassword; Database = Geometronics";
        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(ConStr))
        {

            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("connec2", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
        }

        string errmsg = "";

        if (errmsg != "")
        {
            Code = "0"; strReturn = errmsg;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Code = "1";

                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        strReturn += dr[0].ToString();
                    }
                    if (strReturn == "1")
                    {
                        Console.Write("Updated");
                    }

                }
                //TripDT = TripDT.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is ,An error throws out showing function doesnot exist.Am i making mistake in connection string "ConStr = "Server = localhost; Port = 5433; User Id = postgres; Password = DonotShare; Database = Geometronics";" or Is there any mistake in my function.
                               Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe remove your password from the question. Best not to share that.

Comment: If postgres is similar to MS SQL you don't call a function that way. You do something like `SELECT connec2(....`. And your command type probably has to be Text, not StoredProcedure.

Comment: You're using a function when you should be using a stored procedure.